# Как вывести значение по номеру из отсортированного массива?

Tags: php

Допустим отсортировали ассоциативный массив, теперь надо вывести значение по номеру

```
{"id":"84","iduser":"2","name":"4c4e367fa4fea0d449bc8cc2a.jpg","private":"0","path":"\/user\/0M\/0K\/2\/pictures\/","date":"1533662318","type":"photo"}
{"id":"85","iduser":"2","name":"803cd4ce6841823878f188a1c.jpg","private":"0","path":"\/user\/0M\/0K\/2\/pictures\/","date":"1533662317","type":"photo"}
{"id":"83","iduser":"2","name":"1a0f48b8bb51abf15818e37c7.jpg","private":"0","path":"\/user\/0M\/0K\/2\/pictures\/","date":"1533662314","type":"photo"}
```

Он отсортирован по юникс метке, теперь допустим нужно вывести 1 или второй элемент этого отсортированного массива, как это сделать?

Comment: `$array[0]` и `$array[1]`, не?

Comment: `$a[array_keys($a)[0]]` ?

Comment: Если первый элемент, то привильнее будет `reset($array)`

Comment: Вы можете нормально задать вопрос, что значение, а что номер?

Comment: Смотрите, надо выводить фото для аякс слайдера в порядке от последнего к первому, первое фото самое новое у него в данном примере id84, за ним надо вывести id85... проблема в том что надо как-то выводить массивы из ассоциативного просто зная его номер в отсортированном ассоциативном ( как лучше это сделать) в данном случае поле id никак не поможет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Допустим отсортировали ассоциативный массив

Просто сортируйте без сохранения ключей.

```
$data = [
    'a' => ['id' => 1, 'k' => 3],
    'b' => ['id' => 2, 'k' => 1],
    'c' => ['id' => 3, 'k' => 4],
];

usort($data, function($a, $b){ return $a['k'] <=> $b['k'];});


for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); ++$i) {
    echo json_encode($data[$i]), PHP_EOL;
}
```

> ```
> {"id":2,"k":1}
> {"id":1,"k":3}
> {"id":3,"k":4}
> ```

---

Того же можно добиться «сбросив» ключи:

```
 $data = array_values($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если по ключам вывести элементы массива нет возможности - попробуйте следующие варианты:
1) функция [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-shift.php).
2) комбинирование функций [current и next](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.current.php).